# SqlCommand AddWithValue not working properly

Tags: c#, sql

I have the following block of code...  `fieldCount` always returns 0.

I suspect `AddWithValue` isn't forming the `SELECT` statement properly... Any ideas why?  As you can see from the Watch, they (`field`, `fieldId`) have valid values.

```
public void deleteRows(string table, string field, string fieldId)
{
    int fieldCount;
     using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(String.Format("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {0} WHERE @field IN (@fieldId)", table), connection))
    {
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@field", field);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fieldId", fieldId);
        fieldCount = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();
    }
    if (fieldCount > 0)
    {
```

[image: Debug screen]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parameterizing an SQL IN clause?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterizing-an-sql-in-clause)

Comment: Look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/337792/961113) from the linked duplicate question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two errors in your code:

First, you cannot use a parameter to express a table name or a column name. So your field parameter is not valid in this context.

Second, you cannot use a parameter to express the whole set of values for the IN clause. In your example the parameter @fieldID will be translated in

```
WHERE ..... IN ('1,2,3,4')
```

It will be treated as a string not as the individual values to be included in your where context-

For the field part, **if you are absolutely sure** that the `string field` parameter passed to your method is not typed directly by your user then you could use a string concatenation expression (well you are already doing this for the table so the warning is good also for that value)

```
String.Format("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {0} WHERE {1} IN (....)", table, field);
```

For the IN part, I suggest, instead of passing the string, to build, in the calling function, a list of parameters to be added at the query.

```
public void deleteRows(string table, string field, List<SqlParameter> inParameters)
{

    StringBuilder sb new StringBuilder();
    sb.AppendFormat("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {0} WHERE {1} IN (", table, field));
    using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
    {
        cmd.Connection = connection;
        // Loop over the parameter list, adding the parameter name to the 
        // IN clause and the parameter to the SqlCommand collection
        foreach(SqlParameter p in inParameters)
        {
            sb.Append(p.Name + ",");
            cmd.Parameters.Add(p);
        }

        // Trim out the last comma
        sb.Length--;
        // Close the IN clause
        sn.Append(")";
        cmd.CommandText = sb.ToString();
        fieldCount = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();
    }

}
```